# How to access previous state of Entity?

Tags: java, jpa, entity

I am trying to detect changes in an **Entity**, in order to detect changes made to the entity so I can **log** the changes made for any user.

By now I have managed to use:

```
@EntityListeners(AuditListener.class)
@Entity
public class Entity1{...}
```

and,

```
public class AuditListener {
@PostPersist
@PostUpdate
public void setUserInformation(Object entity) {...}
}
```

Now, what I would like to have is a way to read the **Previous State** of the Entity so I can compare it to the current values and write to an Audit Table the fields, the new values and the user that executed the modifications.

I know I could use **@PostLoad** and save in memory a previous state, but I think there must be a more generic way to accomplish the same (less hardcoded).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello @MДΓΓБДLL, because `@PrePersist/@PreUpdate` are executed just before the `Persist/Update` take place and I need an Initial State (the same data as when it's first loaded). I have read somewhere that the **PersistenceContext** saves an Initial Stateof every Entity in case it needs to execute a Rollback, but still have not found the implementation to access that state.

Comment: Gotcha. Sorry that wasn't useful.

Comment: Can't you reload the entity in the setUserInformation method?

Comment: To create an audity log you only need to save the latest state. You don't actualy need the current state. The current state is the last audity log for that entity. On the method setUserInformation, just save the object id, the user and the date for example. The state before the current one is already in the audity log. Does it makes sense?

Comment: There are still use cases which would benefit from this, hibernate allowed to access it in its on flush dirty event http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html I am surprised to find that JPA doesn't have anything for this

Answer (score 0):

Roolback not return  an entity to its  pre-updated/pre-persisted  state it revert any changes on database .I think there is no such an  object in persistence contex.I think you should use aspect .